# I got error message while checking db connection in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have design a jsp page to check db connection. I am using xampp I got error message while execution.

---

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<% 
  String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost3306//MariaDB";
  Connection con;
   try
    {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");//connect with xampp
    }
 catch(Exception e)
   {
         out.println("error");
    } 
 %>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<% 
  String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//MariaDB"; //Missing colon(:) between localhost and port number
  Connection con;
   try
    {
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");//connect with xampp
    }
 catch(Exception e)
   {
         e.printStackTrace(); //add this line So you can find root cause of error
         out.println("error");
    } 
 %>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also check that you have added mysql connector jar to its classpath

Comment: Can you please help me to set classpath for dbconnection

Comment: add mysql-connector-java jar to lib(web-inf-->lib) folder